# How to calculate the median in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, group-by, median

I have created a basic database (picture attached) [Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ashyu.png), I am trying to find the following:

"Median total amount spent per user in each calendar month"

I tried the following, but getting errors:

```
SELECT 
user_id,
AVG(total_per_user)
FROM (SELECT user_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY total_per_user DESC) AS desc_total,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY total_per_user ASC) AS asc_total
      FROM (SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at) AS calendar_month,
            user_id,    
            SUM(amount) AS total_per_user
            FROM transactions
            GROUP BY calendar_month, user_id) AS total_amount   
      ORDER BY user_id) AS a
WHERE asc_total IN (desc_total, desc_total+1, desc_total-1)
GROUP BY user_id
;
```

Comment: what errors?  we can't help you if you don't tell us the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Postgres, you could just use [aggregate function `percentile_cont()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.25.17.2.2.2.1.1):

```
select 
    user_id,
    percentile_cont(0.5) within group(order by total_per_user) median_total_per_user
from (
    select user_id, sum(amount) total_per_user
    from transactions
    group by date_trunc('month', created_at), user_id
) t
group by user_id
```

Note that `date_trunc()` is probably closer to what you want than `extract(month from ...)` - unless you do want to sum amounts of the same month for different years together, which is not how I understood your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`percentile_cont()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html).  I don't fully understand the question.  If you want the median of the monthly spending, then:

```
SELECT user_id,
       PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY total_per_user
        ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY total_per_user DESC) AS desc_total,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY total_per_user ASC) AS asc_total
FROM (SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at) AS calendar_month,
             user_id, SUM(amount) AS total_per_user
      FROM transactions t
      GROUP BY calendar_month, user_id
     ) um   
GROUP BY user_id;
```

There is a built-in function for median.  No need for fancier processing.